# Why is a Python shelf file containing very little data so large on macOS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos-high-sierra, shelve

I was just following along an example given in a book to illustrate the Python `shelve` module on macOS High Sierra.

As shown below only two small tuples of short strings get stored in a shelf. And as you can see in the very last line, the resulting file is 16 Megabyte large.

The resulting file only gets that large when I try the example on macOS High Sierra with the Python version installed through Homebrew (either 3.6.4 or 2.7.14). If I run it on a Linux host or with the pre-installed Python version (2.7.10) or with Python 3.6.4 installed through the official installer in macOS, the resulting `addresses` file is just a few Kilobyte large, just as reported by others in the comments (thanks!).

```
 ~/tmp> rm addresses
 ~/tmp> python3
Python 3.6.4 (default, Jan  6 2018, 18:43:09)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
[...]
>>> import shelve
>>> book = shelve.open("addresses")
>>> book['flintstone'] = ('fred', '555-1234', '1233 Bedrock Place')
>>> book['rubble'] = ('barney', '555-4321', '1235 Bedrock Place')
>>> book.close()
>>>
 ~/tmp> ll
total 32768
-rw-r--r--  1 moritz  staff    16M Jan 24 13:05 addresses
```

Comment: It's only 16 **kB** on my system. Also Python 3.6.4, but on Arch Linux. It looks like `shelve` can use one of several implementations, which might account for the difference.

Comment: Good to know, must be something with my setup, then! Strange...

Comment: I bet your addresses shelve file contains more than just that. If I try to reproduce your problem, I get three files (bak, dat, dir), with about 650 bytes altogether.

Comment: Did you remove any file starting with `addresses` prior to executing the above code?

Comment: @L3viathan: Yes, I did, you can see it in the code I posted, the very first line says `rm addresses`. I just tried the exact same example on a Linux host and the resulting file is just 13K!

Comment: What flags is `ll` using?

Comment: "Just 13K" is still pretty unbelievable. In my recent Python 3.5.3 on Windows 10, I also get a file as little as 650 bytes. (Most of it is zeroes; more than 400, between Fred and Barney.)

Comment: @EmilVikström: `ls -lh`. @usr2564301: Well, yeah, I don't know, I'd still be happy with 13K instead of 16M... :)

Comment: 16 kB on my system. Python 3.6.1 on macOS.

Comment: @EmilVikström: How did you install Python? I tried again with Python 2.7.14 installed through Homebrew, and the resulting file is also 16M large. Looks like it's something specific about the Homebrew version!

Comment: Yup, it's definitely something about the Homebrew version. I installed Python 3.6.4 through the official installer and with that the shelf file also only gets to 16K.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could confirm this behavior is introduced by gdbm 1.14, gdbm is the library used by `shelve` to access database file.

With [change 2e8a5e0](http://git.gnu.org.ua/cgit/gdbm.git/diff/src/mmap.c?id=2e8a5e0be7b2db179018c10248a6cc64f9db3314), gdbm will try to extend file size to match `next_block_size`. `next_block_size` is calculated by `4 * block_size`, 
which is the optimal I/O block size of underlying filesystem, [obtained by `stat.st_blksize` returned by `stat(2)`](http://git.gnu.org.ua/cgit/gdbm.git/tree/src/gdbmopen.c#n194). On my macOS 10.13.3, a file on APFS on SSD volume, `stat.st_blksize` is 4194304 bytes, `next_block_size` is 16777216 bytes, therefore the init db file size is 16MB.

ps: I examined an HFS+ fs on an HDD volume at my hand, `st_blksize` value is 4096 bytes.